# Database Design with JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa

Say I have a User object that, and that user can have a set of tasks. My front-end may send requests that will perhaps request the entire set of tasks, or make the request with some filters attached (i.e. only send back tasks that are due tomorrow). As of now, I have it like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Task> tasks;
}
```

This makes sense if I want to get ALL the tasks that a user has, but what if I want to filter these tasks somehow? Would I keep it this way, and in my DAO, write a query that queried the Tasks table (with the appropriate filters), or should I read all the tasks into the User object first, then filter once its loaded? I was just wondering what made the most sense in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation.

I think that you should `filter` your tasks in your `query` like using `where column_name = 'value'` in your `DAO` **when** the query is not in a loop situation.

because when It is in a loop, it will recursively use querying to your Database Server.

If it's not a recursive situation. you can retrieve all your `tasks` in one shot, and filter it using the syntax of java.

Answer (score 0):

You use `(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`  but I not recommend eager.

> **How to Enable Lazy Loading in Hibernate**
>
> Before moving further, it is important to recap the default behavior
>   of lazy loading in case of using hibernate mappings vs annotations.
>   The default behavior is to load ‘property values eagerly’ and to load
>   ‘collections lazily’. Contrary to what you might remember if you have
>   used plain Hibernate 2 (mapping files) before, where all references
>   (including collections) are loaded eagerly by default. Also note that
>   @OneToMany and @ManyToMany associations are defaulted to LAZY loading;
>   and @OneToOne and @ManyToOne are defaulted to EAGER loading. This is
>   important to remember to avoid any pitfall in future. To enable lazy
>   loading explicitly you must use "fetch = FetchType.LAZY" on a
>   association which you want to lazy load when you are using hibernate
>   annotations. An example usage will look like this: **@OneToMany(
>   mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY ) private Set products;
>   Another attribute parallel to "FetchType.LAZY" is "FetchType.EAGER"
>   which is just opposite to LAZY i.e. it will load association entity as
>   well when owner entity is fetched first time.** How Lazy Loading Works
>   in Hibernate The simplest way that Hibernate can apply lazy load
>   behavior upon your entities and associations is by providing a proxy
>   implementation of them. Hibernate intercepts calls to the entity by
>   substituting a proxy for it derived from the entity’s class. Where the
>   requested information is missing, it will be loaded from the database
>   before control is ceded to the parent entity’s implementation. Please
>   note that when the association is represented as a collection class,
>   then a wrapper (essentially a proxy for the collection, rather than
>   for the entities that it contains) is created and substituted for the
>   original collection. When you access this collection proxy then what
>   you get inside returned proxy collection are not proxy entities;
>   rather they are actual entities. You need not to put much pressure on
>   understanding this concept because on runtime it hardly matters.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But that isn't exactly my problem - I know how to load it all into memory. I'm just wondering _if_ I should do that, or I should instead manually build a SQL query that filters for me instead of filtering **after** fetching all of them.